# Sending delete over Curl to a Rails backend with CSRF

Tags: ruby-on-rails, curl, csrf

I have a Rails 5.2.x app and I want to delete an item using curl but how do I get and pass the CSRF correctly?

I've put the CSRF into the header when getting the listing

```
  def index
    @asset_items = AssetItem.all
    response.headers["CSRF"]=form_authenticity_token
  end
```

Get listing header

```
$ curl -I http://localhost:9000/asset_items.json
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Download-Options: noopen
X-Permitted-Cross-Domain-Policies: none
Referrer-Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
CSRF: tp6PqomUZtuUSvWAcWfmQcEoIboWphJucSBXo5fYmvspyzYHTK0HTa02slqNmtaxKoTtzOxGVkKqOMxqU7RE0Q==
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
ETag: W/"fb7920f0ce6940c518d3e35d2fa342a8"
Cache-Control: max-age=0, private, must-revalidate
Set-Cookie: XSRF-TOKEN=6Eg0FcruMqGNWZDhXtlxT9%2FnFmCwC675smJnCj3pn4J3HY24D9dTN7Ql1zuiJEG%2FNEvaFkrr6tVpevzD%2BYVBqA%3D%3D; path=/
Set-Cookie: _personal_property_rails_prototype_session=UApETeV6aMxb8XyoxOaM4Z3vnAHkM37bfMWTalFxkU4PDSEhL19mFzZAdEIotkBks8IE7aCsHhJsJRTJjQPHlyKyhFFtm%2Bi%2BOuLr8s0Sp%2B3fJHPWh3OCXovKxLjw8AOxQ%2FPjrAvWSlSWgITybq4%3D--jQVJGziJDd2FKGr%2B--FLu9WqvAWsCKzEr%2BfDXrsg%3D%3D; path=/; HttpOnly
X-Request-Id: db737c7e-7ae1-4698-bada-6585edaf4933
X-Runtime: 0.016735
Vary: Origin
```

Record the CSRF

```
 | CSRF     | tp6PqomUZtuUSvWAcWfmQcEoIboWphJucSBXo5fYmvspyzYHTK0HTa02slqNmtaxKoTtzOxGVkKqOMxqU7RE0Q== |
```

Delete id 99 (fails)

```
 curl -X "DELETE" http://localhost:9000/asset_items/99
```

Delete id 99 but pass the CSRF from the listing header (fails)

```
 curl -X "DELETE" http://localhost:9000/asset_items/99?authenticity_token="tp6PqomUZtuUSvWAcWfmQcEoIboWphJucSBXo5fYmvspyzYHTK0HTa02slqNmtaxKoTtzOxGVkKqOMxqU7RE0Q=="
```

Where %2B equals +

Tried with sending the token as data (fails)

```
 curl -X "DELETE" http://localhost:9000/asset_items/99 --data "authenticity_token=kRZw5QYfH4BzhsYpuXkO1v/W6luRJXIO87DwDa0jKjHGy0Pnrf6Z1UaVrLo/oJTSTd%2Bf6XFPww8p3opQ0jQ0tA=="
```

On the Rails side I get the error

```
Can't verify CSRF token authenticity.
Completed 422 Unprocessable Entity in 1ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)

ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken (ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken):
```

When posting a delete am I supposed to use the CSRF from the listing which in this case is the last request I made?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to send that as part of the headers, with curl use the -H option.

I used that for example to create users with the api of gitlab to send the authenticity token.